# Is there a way with Gson to retrieve sub JSON object information without having to create custom classes for them?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am using Retrofit and Gson to fetch Json and convert data form the OpenWeatherMap API, i was hoping that there is a way to omit the need to write sub-classes for each nested object.

And just to as for your opinion what do you think of this code:

**My goal was to enable accessing the properties directly**

**Would you scream at the monitor if you saw this or is it OK**

```
class PlaceWeatherInfo(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    private val weather: List<Weather>,
    private val wind: Wind,
    @SerializedName("coord") val latLng: LatLng,
    @SerializedName("dt") val time : Long,
    @SerializedName("main") private val mainInfo: MainInfo,
    @SerializedName("sys") private val countryInfo: Country
){
    val weatherType   get() = weather[0].type 
    val description   get() = weather[0].description
    val temp          get() = mainInfo.temp
    val minTemp       get() = mainInfo.minTemp
    val maxTemp       get() = mainInfo.maxTemp
    val feelsLikeTemp get() = mainInfo.feelsLike
    val pressure      get() = mainInfo.pressure
    val humidity      get() = mainInfo.humidity
    val windSpeed     get() = wind.speed
    val windDegree    get() = wind.degree
    val country       get() = countryInfo.country
    val sunrise       get() = countryInfo.sunrise
    val sunset        get() = countryInfo.sunset

}
```

Just so you know i am new to android development and do not have to much experience with Gson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you always use "JSON To Kotlin Class ​(JsonToKotlinClass)​" plugin for that stuff:
(Never manual create classes from JSON)

Link plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-/

Demo:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

json actually is actually HashMap or ArrayList

You just need to read slowly layer by layer

for example (by firebase)：

```
    public static void getCourse_class(){
    DatabaseReference database_course = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("course").child("0001");
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ 
              HashMap<String,Objest> hashmap = ds.getKey();
              String s = hashmap.get("coord").get("dt").get("main").get("sys");

            }
         }
      }
    }
```